# how to refresh the page when i click the asp image button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When i click the image button, page should refresh and show the data i tried in javascipt ,jquery but i am  not getting please someone help for this..

Thanks in Advance.

here is my code : 
report.ascx

```
 <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-right: 0px;">

                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewReport" ImageUrl="../../../_layouts/15/1033/IMAGES/eContracts/view-report-btn.png" runat="server" Text="View Report" 
                                 OnClientClick="ShowFilters(); return true;"/>

                            </td>
```

I used jquery like this, but this is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnViewReport').click(function () { 
    location.reload(true); 
});
```

});

Comment: what happens actually, once you've clicked on it? Because the function `location.reload()` works fine to reload the page.

Comment: when i clicked the button,page not getting reload but after clicking data's are came.

Comment: it might be because the `ShowFilters()` method is calling something like `event.stopPropagation()` . Please once remove `OnClientClick` attribute completely and then see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnViewReport').click(function () { 
    document. location. href=document. location. href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An `ImageButton` control should automatically be triggering a `AutoPostBack` when it is clicked (as it is a button), which should refresh your page. However, it should be noted that this will clear out any Javascript-specific information (as client-side changes are not going to be persisted). You can prevent this postback by returning `false` within your `OnClientClick()` function, however it will not refresh your page.

If you want to refresh a single area of your content without refreshing the entire page, you may want to consider either using an `UpdatePanel` control or using jQuery to make an AJAX request to retrieve your data.

This all depends on if you are trying to persist your client-side changes or not.